# Is there any ways to use react server sent event component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server-sent-events, eventsource

react native supports websocket by default and I saw it on react native documentation.Is there any react native component for eventsource  or can I use react sse component in react native?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple react-native [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) modules:

- [React Native Event Source](https://github.com/jordanbyron/react-native-event-source) (uses a polyfill)
- [React Native EventSource](https://github.com/JonnyBGod/react-native-eventsource)

You may also be able to use a pure JS polyfill directly: [EventSource Client](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) (though it might rely on browser globals not present in react native)